# Knockout: Prevenet a property from adding into a computed's dependency list

Tags: knockout.js, observable

I have an infobox which is either open or closed depending on the value if isVisible property.

```
self.infoboxState = ko.computed(function () {
     if (!ko.computedContext.isInitial()) {
          self.performAdditionalBehaviors();
     }
     return ko.unwrap(self.isVisible)? 'infobox-open' : 'infobox-closed';
}, this);
```

When we set the value of `isVisible` for the second time it would also execute `performAdditionalBehaviors()` method. This method contains an observable property `isDim` and the `infoboxState` becomes dependent on both observables which means any change in the `isDim` property will also now call the `infoboxState`. I verified that from `getDependenciesCount()` which is now set to `2`.

The issue is that I don't want `infoboxState` to get called whenever `isDim` is changed. Is there any way to tell the computed to not add a property into it's dependencies list?

Comment: Include other relevant code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want an observable read within the context of a computed observable to be registered as a dependency, you need to `peek()` at the value instead of simply reading it.

[Controlling dependencies using peek](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-dependency-tracking.html#controlling-dependencies-using-peek)

Furthermore, your `performAdditionalBehaviors()` should not even be in the computed observable.  You want those behaviors to happen if the `isVisible` property changes, you should be subscribing to it instead.

```
this.infoboxState = ko.computed(function () {
     return ko.unwrap(this.isVisible)? 'infobox-open' : 'infobox-closed';
}, this);
this.infoboxState.subscribe(function () {
     this.performAdditionalBehaviors();
}, this);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Problem is that in the `performAdditionalBehaviors` method I am setting value of `isDim` while `peek()` is used just to read the value of a property.

Comment: Setting a value doesn't register as a dependency, only on reads.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeff for clarifying this :) , It is working now. I had already read this article but it was my bad reading(its clearly mentioned there :P) and wrong concept.

Comment: `Peek()` is more good solution. It's a complex application and subscribe is costly and generally should be avoided. Thanks.

Comment: There's not much that different when using subscriptions and computeds, except using a subscription here would be more semantically correct. There are much better patterns to use, but you haven't shown much of your code that we can make an informed suggestion.